# How big was the Puritan cohort in the Anglican church?

Tags: religion, england

I'm mainly interested in the late Elizabethan and Jacobean periods. I've read church publications such as Church Society and AnglicansOnline,as well as all kinds of history websites and blogs, but I cant' find much information regarding my question. I mean they kept track of the number of recusants so why wouldn't they count the number of non-conformist ministers, at least on a diocesan level?

Here is my working definition of "Puritan":

Anyone found guilty of not wearing the required vestments (surplice and tippet, or in a cathedral a cope) or of not using all the prayers, rites, and ceremonies in the Book of Common Prayer.

Comment: What have you read so far?

Comment: Church publications such as Church Society and AnglicansOnline,as well as all kinds of history websites and blogs, but I cant' find much information regarding my question

Comment: Please add your research to your question. (comments get deleted; questions that show preliminary research are less likely to get closed.)  Is it possible that the question has no answer because there was no empirical test for membership in the Puritan cohort?

Comment: I think @MarkCWallace has it right. Roman Catholics were relatively easy to identify - they might *occasionally* take Communion, they would probably marry in an Anglican church as they had no alternative, but would be more than "semi-detached".  "Puritans" were harder to categorize - rather like a modern political parties have Right wings and Left wings, there were "High Church" and "Low Church"  - and to an extent it is in the eye of the beholder - if you're further Left than me, you're a Communist!

Comment: @TheHonRose Yes, just like modern 'evangelicals'. The term has a meaning but who is and isn't an evangelical may be debatable.

Comment: @TheHonRose Here is my working definition of "Puritan": anyone found  guilty of not wearing the required vestments (surplice and tippet, or in a cathedral a cope) or of not using all  the prayers, rites, and ceremonies in the book of common prayer.

Comment: Harry, I added your working definition to your question.